# MVC pattern with Views adapting to different screen resolutions

Tags: ios, oop, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

I'm starting to think about how to solve the problem of developing an app for all iOS devices with different screens (resolution, ratio, retina, etc). I'm working with Adobe Air (AS3), but that really doesn't matter because I'm in a conceptual phase and I'm concerned about the patterns to use.

If I was only developing for iPad, the problem would be as simple as doubling measures and sizes to adapto to retina and non-retina devices. But I need to take into account iPhones, iPods, and eventually Android too with it's myriad of screens.

So far I see those possible options. I'm sorry if there's already some terminology for those options, but I'll just say in it my own words.

- Intelligent views that have some sort of liquid layout, and also intelligent components that adapt to the space the view is assigning to them, and to the screen dpi for font sizes, and image sizes. For example: the view says "here goes a button on the bottom with this width/height". The button already knows what font size the text must be depending on the screen dpi.
- Factorization with parameters of different UI view classes. So I'd have one view class for iPad, another for iPhone, etc. and there would be one class that would factorize the instantiation of the view depending on the device. Each of those classes could be hand tailored to be completely different from each other, but the underlying model and (hopefully) the controller would be the same on every device.
- A middle way approach: One UI View class for tablets, another for phones, and each of those with some sort of liquid capacity to fine tune the position and size of elements (buttons, texts, images, etc).
- External config files that give the View some parameters depending on the device. That would be some sort of custom CSS.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to find this rock on my path.
So how is this problem usually solved?
Is there some stablished pattern for those scenarios?
Is there some reference (book, article) I should read?

I haven't been able to find an in depth answer to this. If it's already been asked/answered please don't downvote. Post the link in the comments and I'll just delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing Responsive Web Design. There are multiple approaches and ways to make you site responsive (i.e. capable of running on multiple screen sizes without having to modify or reconfigure the codebase or rely on user-agent to detect the browser info).

Start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh653584.aspx

Also consider various open-source CSS frameworks that will simplify your life. For example, [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/). Both of those are fairly independent of your development platform and should work well with MVC.

Comment: I'm not making a website... and I'm not using HTML/CSS either.